# "Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression" in query builder with non related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have four entities: `OfficialDocument`, `Media`, `NMediaStatus` and `NMediaType`. I'm trying to translate this SQL:

```
SELECT od.media, od.type, od.status, md.url, nms.name 
    FROM official_document od 
    LEFT JOIN media md ON od.media = md.id 
    LEFT JOIN n_media_status nms ON od.status = nms.id
    WHERE od.company = 9
```

to Doctrine Query Builder and this is the result:

```
public function findOfficialDocument($company_id) {
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('od.media', 'od.type', 'od.status', 'md.url', 'nms.name', 'nmt.name');
    $qb->from('Company\RegisterCompanyBundle\Entity\OfficialDocument', 'od');
    $qb->leftJoin('Common\MediaBundle\Entity\Media', 'md', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'od.media = md.id');
    $qb->leftJoin('Common\MediaBundle\Entity\NMediaStatus', 'nms', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'od.status = nms.id');
    $qb->leftJoin('Common\MediaBundle\Entity\NMediaType', 'nmt', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'od.type = nmt.id');

    $qb->where('od.company = ?1');
    $qb->setParameter(1, $company_id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But any time I call the function from my controller I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 10 near 'media, od.type,': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
>
> [1/2] QueryException: SELECT od.media, od.type, od.status, md.url,
>   nms.name, nmt.name FROM
>   Company\RegisterCompanyBundle\Entity\OfficialDocument od LEFT JOIN
>   Common\MediaBundle\Entity\Media md WITH od.media = md.id LEFT JOIN
>   Common\MediaBundle\Entity\NMediaStatus nms WITH od.status = nms.id
>   LEFT JOIN Common\MediaBundle\Entity\NMediaType nmt WITH od.type =
>   nmt.id WHERE od.company = ?1

`OfficialDocument` is related to the other three entities, but since I don't need the `reversedBy` in those entities then I tough this is causing the error, or maybe not, not sure about it. Anyway, any advice or help to fix this issue?

PS: I'm using latest Symfony2 and Doctrine2 if you need to take a look to my entities here they are: [OfficialDocument](https://gist.github.com/paquitodev/9786689), [Media](https://gist.github.com/paquitodev/9786734), [NMediaStatus](https://gist.github.com/paquitodev/9786755), [NMediaType](https://gist.github.com/paquitodev/9786772)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I answer myself since I found how to fix it:

```
$qb->select('IDENTITY(od.media)', 'IDENTITY(od.type) AS doc_type', 'IDENTITY(od.status) AS doc_status', 'md.url', 'nms.name', 'nmt.name');
```

Since `od.media`, `od.type`, `od.status` are composite keys then I need to add `IDENTITY` in order to make the query work and fix the issue

Comment: I want to select entity object eg. media, type instead of FK ids, what to do then?

Answer (score 28):

Simply you can use `()` where composite keys exist.

```
$qb->select('(od.media)', '(od.type) AS doc_type', '(od.status) AS doc_status', 'md.url', 'nms.name', 'nmt.name');
```