# Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I get an error which is `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 57 near 'room FROM AppBundle:bookings': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`
I have two entities in AppBundle which are Room and Bookings. once I execute the query I get the error mentionned before.
Here my query :

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
                            'SELECT r ' .
                            'FROM AppBundle:Room r ' .
                            'WHERE r NOT IN ( ' .
                            'SELECT b.room ' .
                            'FROM AppBundle:Bookings b ' .
                            'WHERE NOT ( ' .
                            'b.check_out < :check_in ' .
                            'OR ' .
                            'b.check_in > :check_out ' .
                            ')' .
                            ') ' .
                            'ORDER BY r.id'
                    )
                    ->setParameter('check_in', $request->query->get('check-in'))
                    ->setParameter('check_out', $request->query->get('check-out'));
```

Comment: I think the problem is about the `WHERE NOT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression" in query builder with non related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666692/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression-in-query-builder-wi)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about the `WHERE NOT`. 
try with this query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
                            'SELECT r ' .
                            'FROM AppBundle:Room r ' .
                            'WHERE r NOT IN ( ' .
                            'SELECT b.room ' .
                            'FROM AppBundle:Bookings b ' .
                            'WHERE  ' .
                            'b.check_out < :check_in ' .
                            'OR ' .
                            'b.check_in > :check_out ' .
                            ') ' .
                            'ORDER BY r.id'
                    )
                    ->setParameter('check_in', $request->query->get('check-in'))
                    ->setParameter('check_out', $request->query->get('check-out'));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the query is working fine when I execute it in MySQL Database. the problem not in the query syntax.

Comment: could you please write it with createQueryBuilder ?