# Invalid PathExpression must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am currently working in a project using Symfony3.4, a project is about booking rooms of an hotel.
I have two entities `room(id,...)` and `bookings(room,check_in,check_out,...)` and the relation between them is `OneToMany`.
I am trying to retrieve rooms that are not booked by `check_in` and `check_out` fields.
I did a function in `RoomRepository` called `findRoomsNotBookedByCheckInCheckOut`

```
public function findRoomsNotBookedByCheckInCheckOut(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT r FROM AppBundle:Room r "
        . "WHERE r NOT IN ( "
        . "SELECT b.room FROM AppBundle:Bookings b "
        . "WHERE NOT ( "
        . "b.checkOut <= :checkIn "
        . "OR b.checkIn >= :checkOut "
        . ") "
        . ") ORDER BY r.id")
        ->setParameter('checkIn', "'".$request->query->get('check-out')."'")
        ->setParameter('checkOut', "'".$request->query->get('check-in')."'");

        die($q->getSQL());
        return $q->getResult();
    }
```

When I call this function from the controller

```
private function roomsByCheckInCheckOut(Request $request, $em) {
        if ($request->query->get('check-in') != null && $request->query->get('check-out') != null) {

           $rooms = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Room')->findRoomsNotBookedByCheckInCheckOut($request);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I get an error which is :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 57 near 'room FROM AppBundle:Bookings': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

I tried to fixed by change the `b.room` to `b.room.id` :

```
public function findRoomsNotBookedByCheckInCheckOut(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT r FROM AppBundle:Room r "
        . "WHERE r NOT IN ( "
        . "SELECT b.room.id FROM AppBundle:Bookings b "
        . "WHERE NOT ( "
        . "b.checkOut <= :checkIn "
        . "OR b.checkIn >= :checkOut "
        . ") "
        . ") ORDER BY r.id")
        ->setParameter('checkIn', "'".$request->query->get('check-out')."'")
        ->setParameter('checkOut', "'".$request->query->get('check-in')."'");

        die($q->getSQL());
        return $q->getResult();
    }
```

and I get another error which is :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 'id FROM AppBundle:Bookings': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Bookings has no field or association named room.id
```

which is logic because the entity `bookings` does not have a `room.id` but it has `room`.
I tried again to solve by changing `b.room` to `b` and the function become :

```
public function findRoomsNotBookedByCheckInCheckOut(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT r FROM AppBundle:Room r "
        . "WHERE r NOT IN ( "
        . "SELECT b FROM AppBundle:Bookings b "
        . "WHERE NOT ( "
        . "b.checkOut <= :checkIn "
        . "OR b.checkIn >= :checkOut "
        . ") "
        . ") ORDER BY r.id")
        ->setParameter('checkIn', "'".$request->query->get('check-out')."'")
        ->setParameter('checkOut', "'".$request->query->get('check-in')."'");

        die($q->getSQL());
        return $q->getResult();
    }
```

it worked fine without any error but it didn't retrieve the right result.
**note: I tested the sql query in MySQL database and I get the right result**

Comment: Haven't you asked the same thing yesterday? ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872448/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression)). Why do you ask the same once again? I provide you with a [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666692/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression-in-query-builder-wi) if it didn't work then create a new answer with a different title and better readability. Voting this to be closed!!

Comment: @ReynierPM thank you for your contribution even it was so bad. if you don't like my posts please don't post again.

Comment: You should read and learn how to use SO properly before post the same once and again anyways do not expect any of us to do your job what you should expect is to research and learn - something that you didn't practice often. If you take a look to my previous answer (just yesterday) and this one is exactly what I have posted as a solution on my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved my problem by adding `IDENTITY(b.room)`.

```
$q = $em->createQuery("SELECT r.id FROM AppBundle:Room r "
        . "WHERE r.id NOT IN ( "
        . "SELECT IDENTITY(b.room) FROM AppBundle:Bookings b "
        . "WHERE NOT ( "
        . "b.checkOut < :checkIn "
        . "OR b.checkIn > :checkOut "
        . ") "
        . ") ORDER BY r.id")
        ->setParameter('checkIn', $chIn)
        ->setParameter('checkOut', $chOut);
```

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, do you have any documentation about the use of IDENTITY()?...i Have the same problem as you and resolved used this function...thanks