# Regex with doctrine "Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression."

Tags: regex, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a `$value` variable containing "Open|Close". I would like to use a doctrine query in Symfony to get all "status" with the word "Open" or "Close". For that I try to use a regex. However, I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'status, :regexp)': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Here is my code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
->andWhere('REGEXP(q.status, :regexp) = true')
->setParameter('regexp', '|');
```

I have the `DoctrineExtensionsBundle` and I have updated my `app/config.yml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression" in query builder with non related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666692/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression-in-query-builder-wi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the explode() function and SQL IN operator ?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
  ->andWhere('q.status IN (:status)')
  ->setParameter(':status', explode('|', $value));
```

It will return all records having either "Open" or "Close" in the status column.

Comment: I have been stuck since Friday on this problem and you have just found a solution that works very well. Big thanks